# rename columns containing pattern in r using plyr rename function

Tags: r, rename, design-patterns, plyr, multiple-columns

I would like to rename all columns in a dataframe containing a pattern in r.  Ie, I would like to substitute the column name "variable" for all columns containing "variable", such as "htn.variable".  I thought I could use rename from `plyr` and `grepl`.  I have created an example:

```
exp<-data.frame(htn.variable = c(1,2,3), id = c(5,6,7), visit = c(1,3,4))
require(plyr)
rename ( exp, c(
names(exp)[grepl ( 'variable',names(exp))] = "variable" ))
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: unexpected '=' in:
>   " c(
>   names(exp)[grepl ( 'variable',names(exp))] ="

I think this has to do with calling up a name within a function, and I would like to ask if anyone might have a suggestion how to make this work please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Why bother with `rename` at all?

```
colnames(exp)[grepl('variable',colnames(exp))] <- 'variable'
```

Comment: this is elegant, thanks for sharing. I am always surprised how easy it is to get around a for loop.

Comment: nice solution +1! the only 'competitor' would be `setnames` from `data.table`, which works with `df` as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to replace the part of the column name that is equal to 'variable', use:

```
colnames(exp) <- gsub('variable', 'replace string', colnames(exp))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rename ( exp, “variable” = names(exp)[grepl ( 'variable',names(exp))])
```

Comment: Please add at least a simple sentence explaining what that does.

Answer (score -3):

I am not 100% sure if this is what you need but it may be a start. I stayed away from plyr

```
for (i in 1:ncol(exp)){
    if (substr(names(exp)[i],5,12) == "variable"){
        names(exp)[i] <- "new.variable"    #or any new var name 
    }
}
exp
```

You could also just remove the first four elements of the variable name.

Comment: What is the downvote for? It is not the best answer but it is not "not useful". It is feasible and will do what the submitter needs.

Comment: I'm speculating here, but I'd imagine that some deficiencies include (1) the lack of vectorization when a vectorized option is readily available, (2) using `substr` is fragile, since the OP only mentioned names _containing_ the string "variable", and this assumes that the string occurs after precisely 4 characters each time.

Comment: the main issues have been pointed by @joran. But also (sorry if I'm too meticulous) you use too many paranthesis... since both the `for` and `if` have just one expression inside them you don't need the curly braces, which make the code slower. It may seem wierd but, espacially in simple math computatio (when most of the time is spent just in looping), you can have the code with the `{` to be 40% slower.

Comment: Hi Michelle, this is interesting, I was not aware that curly braces will slow down the code. I use them regardless for clarity and structure. Regardless, this is helpful feedback. On more a meta level: downvoting a comment that is functional (although clearly not the optimal) takes any motivation out of SO members to help others. Unless something is clearly wrong and misleading I think a non-vote would be more appropriate than a downvote.